# How to choose a value of a HashMap in select Struts2?

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, ognl

I ran into a problem with Struts2. I have a `HashMap<String, Integer>` that I use in a form with a *select* to choose name and corresponding id to that name.

`HashMap` iterates and populates my `<select>`list with names. I only need an id to pick. How do I pick an id/value instead of a name/key?

companyMap is a `HashMap`, where `<String, Integer>` or key, value.

`companyName` is a String.

```jsp
<s:select label="Pick the company name" 
    headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Company name"
    list="companyMap.keys" 
    name = "companyName"
/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the list is a Map (key, value), the Map key will become the option 'value' parameter and the Map value will become the option body.

But you need to change this rule

```jsp
<s:select label="Pick the company name" 
    headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Company name"
    list="%{companyMap.entrySet()}" 
    name = "companyId"
    listKey="value"
    listValue="key"
/>
```